# Doubt regading an equaiton on finding the general value of theta for $\sec 4θ − \sec 2θ = 2$ given as solution on a website

Tags: trigonometry

Question 2: If $\sec 4θ − \sec 2θ = 2$, then the general value of $θ$ is __________.

The solution for this is given as

Solution:

$\sec 4θ − \sec 2θ = 2 ⇒ \cos 2θ − \cos 4θ = 2 \cos 4θ \cos 2θ$

$⇒ −\cos 4θ = \cos 6θ$

$⇒ 2 \cos 5θ \cosθ = 0$

⇒ $H = [h \cot 15°] / [\cot 15° − 1]$ or

$nπ/5 + π/10$

My Doubt is

how come  this equation . **Is this correct**

$$H = [h \cot 15°] / [\cot 15° − 1]$$

Can anyone please clarify or give the proof of this equation and how this equation suits in solving this particular problem

This is solved in this site
[Bijus IIT Trignometry past solutions](https://byjus.com/jee/jee-main-maths-trigonometry-previous-year-questions-with-solutions/)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun ...thanks ...I am new to these things ...thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend against having your contact number in your profile. It's not secure.

Comment: What is $H$ or $h$? That line in the solution does not make sense

Comment: @Shaun ..Ok i shall remove that ..Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Andrei ..Thanks a lot ..I thought that it was due to my ignorance i couldn't understand that ...

Comment: The step between $2 \cos 5 \theta \cos \theta = 0$ and the solution is likely an error that belonged to one of the other questions further below (Question 13, most likely).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sec 4θ − \sec 2θ &= 2 \\
\\
\frac{1}{\cos4θ }-\frac{1}{\cos2θ }&=2 \tag{1}\\
\\
 \cos 2θ − \cos 4θ &= 2 \cos 4θ \cos 2θ\tag{2}\\
\\
 \cos 2θ − \cos 4θ &= \cos 6θ +\cos 2θ\tag{3}\\
\\
  − \cos 4θ &= \cos 6θ \tag{4}\\
\\
  \cos 6θ+ \cos 4θ &=0  \tag{5}\\
\\
 2 \cos 5θ \cosθ &= 0\tag{6}\\
\\
⇒~~~~\cos 5θ=0~~&~ \text{or}~~~\cos θ=0\tag{7}
\end{align}$$

$(1)$ to $(2):~~$ $\text{Multiply} ~~\cos(2\theta)\cos(4\theta) ~~\text{on both sides}$

$(2)$ to $(3):~~$ $\text{RHS use} ~~2\cos(a)\cos(b)=\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$

$(3)$ to $(4):~~$ $\text{Cancel} ~~\cos(2\theta)~~\text{on both sides}$

$(4)$ to $(5):~~$ $\text{Add} ~~\cos(4\theta)~~\text{on both sides}$

$(5)$ to $(6):~~$ $\text{LHS use} ~~\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$

Now you can go from Eq.$(7)$

Comment: ..Thanks for your beautiful and elaborate explanation ... but actually my doubt was  H = [h cot 15o] / [cot 15o − 1]  ..what this line was ,,,@Andrei  made it clear that was a nonsense made from the guys who gave the solution ...and that dosent make any sense here...Any way thanks a lot

Comment: I can't read, what is your h and H?

Comment: can you please refer the link of the site i have already posted .The question is solved there ..it is second question...and h and H are told in the second last line of solution.there...e ..I too didn't understand what formulae was ..That is why i posted this question...

Comment: https://byjus.com/jee/jee-main-maths-trigonometry-previous-year-questions-with-solutions/

Comment: I can't see it, when click the link, it says: Access denied
You do not have access to byjus.com.

The site owner may have set restrictions that prevent you from accessing the site. Contact the site owner for access or try loading the page again.